# Get my site session in wordpress?

Tags: php, functions, session

I am using a custom site build in zend frameword, i also have a wordpress installed in this directory, for example:

```
www.mywordpressSite.com // here is my wordpress site..
www.mywordpressSite.com/frameWorkSite // here is my framework site..
```

All i need to get a framwork session inside wordpress theme, i tried by accessing direcct like,

```
$_SESSION['userId'];
```

I tried by making a class in framework and by including this in my wordpress site, but in vain..

Any helpful idea is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress doesn't use PHP session (`$_SESSION`). If you want to use it you need to do at your own. For example:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_session_start', 1);
function wpse_session_start() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

But, if you want is to get the user id of the current user, you can use [`get_current_user_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id):

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>
```

Comment: but, if i am setting session something like, $_SESSION['myUserIdFromFramework'] from framework while user is getting login there, how do i get this in wordpress, i am entirely new to wordpress, i don't even know that, this type of functionality is possible in wordpress or not, i am sure that Facebook allows this if we are using their API.